# httpd service is failed to start on container restart

Tags: docker

My httpd service is not starting on container restart.

## Dockerfile

```
[root@dev devops_pratice]# cat Dockerfile 
FROM custom_centos:6
VOLUME ["/opt/shared/finapp1usr/public_html","/var/www/html/","/opt/shared/finapp1usr/logs","/var/log/httpd"]
CMD ["service httpd start"]
EXPOSE 80 2000
```

=====================================================

## I've Build an image from this Dockerfile

```
[root@dev devops_pratice]# docker build -t custom_centos6:v7 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  273.9kB
Step 1/4 : FROM custom_centos:6
 ---> 23bfa4993b72
Step 2/4 : VOLUME ["/opt/shared/finapp1usr/public_html","/var/www/html/","/opt/shared/finapp1usr/logs","/var/log/httpd"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> de74675b273a
Step 3/4 : CMD ["service httpd start"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6b77b5b11feb
Step 4/4 : EXPOSE 80 2000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 55975ece7996
Successfully built 55975ece7996
Successfully tagged custom_centos6:v7
```

=====================================================

## and Finally I've run the container using the above build image custom_centos6:v7

```
[root@dev devops_pratice]# docker run -dit --name financeapp1 --restart unless-stopped custom_centos6:v7 /bin/bash
c46bb112d9edb2f42a28c94d028a9cb2bc0903a10879d44dc15e2445fd584b45
```

=====================================================

## But, while checking the httpd service seems to be dead.

```
[root@dev devops_pratice]# docker exec financeapp1 service httpd status
httpd dead but pid file exists
```

=====================================================
Any idea on this?

Comment: did you test the container from the host side instead (e.g. `wget <CONTAINER_IP>`)?

Comment: When you provide a command like `/bin/bash` at the end of the `docker run` command, that runs _instead of_ the `CMD` in the Dockerfile.  That having been said, that `CMD` won’t work either (because of quoting issues; because the main container process can’t be a background process).  You need to run something like `apachectl` that can start the process as a foreground process, and the lifespan of the container will be the lifespan of that process.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @SeanPianka I think it is obvious that the desired behavior is to get the docker container running the `httpd` service

Comment: following on @DavidMaze comment, you could start the service through service configuration (i.e. make it start at "boot/launch" time) and  then have another command running that checks the health of that service and exits when it finds the service is no longer fit for purpose.